# How to reconstruct a time series knowing time-lapses among rows (Vector `A`) and the time for one specific value of `A`

Tags: r, dplyr, sequence, lubridate

I have a vector `Delay` which represents the time-lapse among different moments in seconds. Below I show a small example:

```
Delay <- c(120,180,90,110)
```

The point is that I want to re-build a serial time using the vector `Delay` and knowing that the time for a specific position of `Delay` (i.e. Delay[3]) is `2016-08-30 12:00:00`. RECONSTRUCTION BACKWARDS AND FORWARDS IS DIFFERENT as you can see in the example below. Starting in our "reference time", moving backwards imply to subtract 90 seconds to `2016-08-30 12:00:00`. Moving forwards implies to add 110 seconds to `2016-08-30 12:00:00`. One final condition is that I want only the serial time between 2 specific dates, for instance, between `2016-08-30 11:38:00` and `2016-08-30 12:19:00` in this example.

What I would expect from this example is this:

```
   Delay            DateTime
1    120 2016-08-30 11:38:50        .                   .                  .
2    180 2016-08-30 11:41:50        .                   .                  .
3     90 2016-08-30 11:43:20        .                   .                  .
4    110 2016-08-30 11:45:10        .                   .                  .
5    120 2016-08-30 11:47:10        .                   .                  .
6    180 2016-08-30 11:50:10        .                   .                  .
7     90 2016-08-30 11:51:40        .                   .                  .
8    110 2016-08-30 11:53:30        .                   .                  .
9    120 2016-08-30 11:55:30  # I have subtracted 180 seconds to the time `2016-08-30 11:58:30`
10   180 2016-08-30 11:58:30  # I have subtracted 90 seconds to the time `2016-08-30 12:00:00`
11    90 2016-08-30 12:00:00  # Starting point from which we move backwards and forwards using the sequence of times specified in `Delay`
12   110 2016-08-30 12:01:50  # I have added 110 seconds to the time `2016-08-30 12:00:00`
13   120 2016-08-30 12:03:50  # I have added 120 seconds to the time `2016-08-30 12:01:50`
14   180 2016-08-30 12:06:50        .                   .                  .
15    90 2016-08-30 12:08:20        .                   .                  .
16   110 2016-08-30 12:10:10        .                   .                  .
17   120 2016-08-30 12:12:10        .                   .                  .
18   180 2016-08-30 12:15:10        .                   .                  .
19    90 2016-08-30 12:16:40        .                   .                  .
20   110 2016-08-30 12:18:30        .                   .                  .
```

How could I afford this?

## Applying the code proposed by @Ian Campbell  but changing vector `Delay` and some of the deadlines I find this:

```
Delay <- c(120,180,90,110,150,170) 
KnownTime <-  as_datetime("2016-08-30 12:00:00")
KnownTimePosition <- 3
TargetTimePast <- as_datetime("2016-08-30 11:38:00")
TargetTimeFuture <- as_datetime("2016-08-30 12:13:00")

DelaySpan <- sum(Delay)
TargetPastSeconds <- time_length(KnownTime - TargetTimePast)
TotalSpan <- time_length(TargetTimeFuture - TargetTimePast)
DelaysBack <- ceiling((TargetPastSeconds - sum(Delay[1:(KnownTimePosition)]))/DelaySpan)
TotalDelays <- ceiling(TotalSpan/DelaySpan)
FullDelayVector <- rep(Delay,TotalDelays)
Start <- KnownTime - seconds(sum(Delay[1:(KnownTimePosition)])) - DelaysBack * DelaySpan

Result <- as_datetime(Reduce(function(x,y){x + seconds(y)},FullDelayVector,Start,accumulate = TRUE))
Result <- Result[Result >=  TargetTimePast & Result <=  TargetTimeFuture]

Result <- as.data.frame(Result)
colnames(Result)[1] <- "DateTimeUTC"
Result

foo <- Result %>%
  arrange(DateTimeUTC) %>%
  mutate(diff = as.POSIXct(DateTimeUTC, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS") - lag(as.POSIXct(DateTimeUTC, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS"), default = as.POSIXct(DateTimeUTC, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")[1]),
         diff_secs = as.numeric(diff, units = 'secs'))
foo

           DateTimeUTC     diff diff_secs
1  2016-08-30 11:39:50   0 secs         0
2  2016-08-30 11:41:50 120 secs       120
3  2016-08-30 11:44:50 180 secs       180
4  2016-08-30 11:46:20  90 secs        90
5  2016-08-30 11:48:10 110 secs       110
6  2016-08-30 11:50:40 150 secs       150
7  2016-08-30 11:53:30 170 secs       170
8  2016-08-30 11:55:30 120 secs       120
9  2016-08-30 11:58:30 180 secs       180
10 2016-08-30 12:00:00  90 secs        90
11 2016-08-30 12:01:50 110 secs       110
12 2016-08-30 12:04:20 150 secs       150
13 2016-08-30 12:07:10 170 secs       170
```

As you see,the initial time for the dataframe is OK since I established as cutoff moment the time `2016-08-30 11:38:00`, so the previous row to the first row in `foo` would be `2016-08-30 11:37:00` (subtracting 170 seconds to `2016-08-30 11:38:00`), which is beyond `2016-08-30 11:38:00` and then it doesn't appear. However, for the other limit of my dataframe `foo`, I find as last time `2016-08-30 12:07:10`, when the limit is `2016-08-30 12:13:00` and hence, there should be some more rows using `Delay` as criteria.

Comment: I am having trouble understanding the logic. Can you please provide your starting data as well?

Comment: Well, in this case, there is no starting data. The only data I have is the vector `Delay`, and from that, I want to built a dataframe following the "rules" I described in the post. In different words from what I said in the post, what I want is to re-built a time-series knowing that the time for `Delay[3]` is `2016-08-30 12:00:00` and knowing that the `Delay` vector describes the time interval between rows in my desired "time-series" dataframe. If you still don't understand, I will try to explain it in other way in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will do what you're asking. We can use `Reduce` to follow along the `Delay` vector. I'll use `lubridate` for convenience

```
library(lubridate)
Delay <- c(120,180,90,110) 
KnownTime <-  as_datetime("2016-08-30 12:00:00")
KnownTimePosition <- 3
TargetTimePast <- as_datetime("2016-08-30 11:38:00")
TargetTimeFuture <- as_datetime("2016-08-30 12:19:00")

DelaySpan <- sum(Delay)
TargetPastSeconds <- time_length(KnownTime - TargetTimePast)
TotalSpan <- time_length(TargetTimeFuture - TargetTimePast)
DelaysBack <- ceiling((TargetPastSeconds - sum(Delay[1:(KnownTimePosition)]))/DelaySpan)
TotalDelays <- ceiling(TotalSpan/DelaySpan)
FullDelayVector <- rep(Delay,TotalDelays)
Start <- KnownTime - seconds(sum(Delay[1:(KnownTimePosition)])) - DelaysBack * DelaySpan

Result <- as_datetime(Reduce(function(x,y){x + seconds(y)},FullDelayVector,Start,accumulate = TRUE))
Result[Result >=  TargetTimePast & Result <=  TargetTimeFuture]
# [1] "2016-08-30 11:38:50 UTC" "2016-08-30 11:41:50 UTC" "2016-08-30 11:43:20 UTC" "2016-08-30 11:45:10 UTC" "2016-08-30 11:47:10 UTC"
# [6] "2016-08-30 11:50:10 UTC" "2016-08-30 11:51:40 UTC" "2016-08-30 11:53:30 UTC" "2016-08-30 11:55:30 UTC" "2016-08-30 11:58:30 UTC"
#[11] "2016-08-30 12:00:00 UTC" "2016-08-30 12:01:50 UTC" "2016-08-30 12:03:50 UTC" "2016-08-30 12:06:50 UTC" "2016-08-30 12:08:20 UTC"
#[16] "2016-08-30 12:10:10 UTC" "2016-08-30 12:12:10 UTC" "2016-08-30 12:15:10 UTC" "2016-08-30 12:16:40 UTC" "2016-08-30 12:18:30 UTC"
```

Comment: Thanks @Ian Campbell, you are pretty close. However, I find some problems. One of them is that when I move backward from the "start time" ("2016-08-30 12:00:00"), the previous time is got by subtracting the `Delay` of the next row/position to the `DateTime` of this same row/position. That is, for instance, in your example, the second position of your vector has the datetime `2016-08-30 11:55:30 UTC`, when I would expect the datetime `2016-08-30 11:58:30` since I have to subtract 90 seconds to the datetime `2016-08-30 12:00:00`.

Comment: When I re-built forward, your code do it properly, so the problem is only when re-building backwards. My other doubt is how to set limits to this reconstruction of a serial time. In this example, as I explained in the post, I would like to re-built a period between `2016-08-30 11:38:00` and `2016-08-30 12:19:00` using repeated times the vector `A`. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: Hi @Ian Campbell, I introduced a small change in `Delay` to check that it works with other lengths and I found a small problem. I introduced one more value in `Delay` (`Delay <- c(120,180,90,110,150)`) and I find that the last date in `Result` is `2016-08-30 12:15:10`. I don't understand why it doesn't add a new row since the limit time is `2016-08-30 12:19:00` and next delay added to `2016-08-30 12:15:10` is 120, so there should be one additional row with the date `2016-08-30 12:17:10`.

Comment: My worry is that I want to make this code generalizable to different types of `Delay` lengths. In my real data `Delay` has around 65000 values, and I want to reconstruct a time series using that `Delay`. Do you know if the code is correct of if I should change something to use a `Delay` like the one I have?

Comment: I tried to explain what I think doesn't work properly with the code just in case you can fix it. I think must be something easy for you. The problem is that the reconstruction of the serial time forwards doesn't work as I would expect. It stops with the last value of `Delay` when I would expect that it starts with the first value of `Delay` when it reaches the last value (as it does moving backwards).

Comment: I think it's a rounding problem, try adding 1 to the the number of times `Delay` is `rep`ed for `FullDelayVector`. IE `FullDelayVector <- rep(Delay,TotalDelays + 1)`

Comment: That works!! Thanks! One doubt, Should I change `1` depending on the situation? I changed the time limits of the dataframe and I saw that what you proposed works well. But since I don't know the meaning of adding `1` to `TotalDelays`, I don't know if I should take care of it or if I should use other value depending on the situation. Thanks again